# How do I make sprouted bread myself?

Tags: bread

There are a few companies out there that offer sprouted bread (e.g. Food for Life).

I am interesting in making bread myself. I have purchased some sprouting containers. Once sprouted the grain obviously is soft and holds a lot of moisture.

Do I have to dry the sprouts and mill them after the drying process or are the grains usually mashed?

Answer (score 6):

You can do either, but personally I have experience with drying and milling.  To dry the sprouts, make sure that you keep them at a low temperature.  You could do this using a dehydrator or in the oven at the lowest possible temperature.  The claim from sprouted grain companies and proponents is that this keeps beneficial enzymes alive.  After this you can mill your grain.  I made the mistake of attempting to mill before fully drying one time - this may clog your machine.  Make sure your sprouts are fully dry before grinding.

Comment: I was thinking about getting a dehydrator. Which grain mill are you using?

Comment: @Andre - I use a grain mill attachment for the KitchenAid, grew up with a Bosch that had a grinder that did an excellent job.  I appreciate multi-taskers.

Answer (score 3):

Susan over on the Wild Yeast blog had a recent posting on sprouting the wheat and then baking the bread.  Take a look:

http://www.wildyeastblog.com/2010/07/16/bbb-sprouted-grain-bread/

Also you can find a lot of really good information about sprouted wheat bread on the Fresh Loaf:

http://www.thefreshloaf.com/